# SVG icon looks different when included in the page

Tags: html, svg

I want to display [this svg](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/98153/721064/AcI0HzP20nr6CbN/fundbase_logo-dacc045568fff9acbb9b19fa09942d85.svg) (this is a download link) in my page. I do that like this:

```
<img alt="logo" src="/assets/logo.svg">
```

But this is the result:

[image]

I have those ugly lines around the central circle but they are not there when I open the SVG file.

Is it a browser bug?

Comment: you have gaps in the image itself.

Comment: It's the background color seeping through the gaps. If you are familiar with print, you need to do some trapping of the color fills. Make the paths overlap a bit.

Comment: I have opend the svg in firefox, chrome, opera and IE; but every browser seems have a bit of these gaps, but they differ in size; so I think, the rendering might not be clearly defined in the standards for your image

Comment: Antialiasing is part of the SVG standard but it's up to the implementation exactly how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called antialiasing and all browsers have it to blend shapes together. It can be disabled by setting shape-rendering="crispEdges" or shape-rendering:crispEdges as a CSS style.

Two of your shapes could do with having this set, the polygon above the circle and the path below it.